# SQL/Impala : return records for non-duplicated object with the latest timestamp

Tags: sql, impala

In Impala/SQL, is it possible to have a query to find the records for non-duplicated objects with their corresponding latest timestamp?

For example, if I have `table_1`:

```
id   |   timestamp
-----------------------
1    |   2016-01-02 
2    |   2016-02-01
1    |   2016-02-04
1    |   2016-03-05
3    |   2016-05-12
3    |   2016-05-15
4    |   2016-07-07
5    |   2016-08-01
```

I would like my query to return the data like below

```
id   |   timestamp
-----------------------
2    |   2016-02-01
1    |   2016-03-05
3    |   2016-05-15
4    |   2016-07-07
5    |   2016-08-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` query like

```
select id, max(timestamp) as maxStamp
from table_1
group by id;
```